# How to find aliasing in images using python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am looking to find aliasing in images , what will be best suited approach .

thanks
nk

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing means that some high-frequency signal shows up as a low-frequency signal. You cannot distinguish this from any true low-frequency signal. Therefore, there is no way to determine if a signal was aliased during sampling or not, unless you have the original continuous-domain signal to compare to.